# gRPC calls through proxy server from .NET client failing after updating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, proxy, grpc, .net-6.0, grpc-dotnet

We have a .NET client Desktop application that makes gRPC calls to our servers using **Grpc.Net.Client** Nuget Package. The application is deployed to one of our customer environments that uses a proxy. After updating the app from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6.0, the application is throwing exception while making the gRPC call.
The exception details are here - *Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (proxy server details) InvalidOperationException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Unable to get subchannel from HttpRequestMessage. (proxy server details)*

Creating the gRPC channel using the below code

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(URI);
```

Is there any known issues with using proxy server on .NET 6.0?
Do I need to set any additional properties while creating the channel?

Comment: is this http? or https?

Comment: this is https @MarcGravell